# Highmaps border color of region

Tags: css, highcharts, highmaps

I am using Highmaps in one of my web based application. Until now it was easy to modify it according to my use case but now i need to changes the border color of the region and i am unable to do it.

Code i have tried but failed:

```
chart: {
                plotBorderColor: '#ffffff',
                borderColor: "#ffffff",
       }
```

See attached image what i want to achieve

[image]

Want to change the outline color to white

http://jsfiddle.net/qLen614m/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `stroke` attribute of the `path` element:

```css
path {
    stroke: white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But where exactly do i need to put it.?

Comment: It's a CSS code, you just put it in your css file/style element. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/ywnr0esa/ I put there `blue` instead of `white` so it will be more visible. You can change to white.

Answer (score 2):

There is an options to set border color for map series. It is borderColor and it should be set in series.

```
series : [{
                borderColor: 'white',
...
```

[API link](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#series<map>.borderColor)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qLen614m/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should use [borderWidth](https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.borderWidth) property for series.

> The border width of each map area.

```
series: [{
        borderWidth: 2
    }]
```

Here is the [official demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/plotoptions/series-border/).